# Sort files Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have this code in Apps Script, it gets all files of a folder (expofd) and print the ID's in the Google Sheet. But each time the code get the files in a different order and I need any kind of sort (Alphabetically by name, not by id) or whatever, but the printing in the Sheet have to be always in the same order. Also, It would be nice a code modification to filter the folder files and get only which have certain suffix.

```
  var list = [];
  list.push(['ID']);
  var files = expofd.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
  file = files.next();
  var row = []
  row.push(file.getId())
  list.push(row)
  ;
  
  }
  
  sh.getRange(2,2,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Tag:java] is not [tag:js]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function myFunction() {
  var expofd = DriveApp.getFolderById('#############') // your folder id
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var suffix = '.pdf' // adapt as necessary
  var list = [];
  var files = expofd.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    list.push([file.getName(),file.getId()])
  }
  var result = [['name','id'], ...list.filter(r => r[0].includes(suffix)).sort()]
  sh.getRange(1,1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

You will get the list sorted by name and filtered by suffix

Comment: Well done! Btw, you can get an active sheet directly from App: `var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`. No need to get a spreadsheet first.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case here is the more fancy (and probably more quick) way to search files with Drive API:

```
function myFunction() {
  var mask = '.jpg';
  var folder_id = '###'; // put your folder ID instead of ###
  var query = `title contains "${mask}" and trashed = false and "${folder_id}" in parents`;
  
  var findings = Drive.Files.list({ q: query }) || [];
  var table = [['name', 'id'], ...findings.items.map(f => [f.title, f.id]).sort()];
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clear().getRange(1,1,table.length,2).setValues(table);
}
```

Make sure you add the Drive API in Script Editor:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Search for files and folders with `Drive.list()` method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files)

Comment: Your solution worked well, but only on my drive. For shared drives I had to use Mike's solution. Do you know how to implement Drive.files.list in shared drives?

Comment: It's an interesting problem. I don't know how it can be done. Probably there is a solution. It worth to post as a new question. It would be good for everyone.