# Sorting files in a list including URL using new methods in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

This is in reference to a previous question about methods of listing files from Google Drive in GAP:

[Sort files Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72752888/sort-files-google-apps-script#new-answer?newreg=5a8c1f190a534aae80e857159dcdc631)

There are two methods in that discussion, a standard method and a faster method. The new method is indeed faster, and I’m wondering, how do I include a file URL for each file in the table that is being generated?

```
function myFunction() {
  var mask = '.jpg';
  var folder_id = '###'; // put your folder ID instead of ###
  var query = `title contains "${mask}" and trashed = false and "${folder_id}" in parents`;
  
  var findings = Drive.Files.list({ q: query }) || [];
  var table = [['name', 'id'], ...findings.items.map(f => [f.title, f.id]).sort()];
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clear().getRange(1,1,table.length,2).setValues(table);
}
```

In the above example, the table creates columns for title and id — I’d like to replace “id” with “url”, but I can’t find the method for referencing the file URL.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file URL instead of the file ID by modifying your script.

Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your expected URL. But, if your expected URLs are like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${id}/view?usp=drivesdk`, `https://docs.google.com/###/d/{id}/edit?usp=drivesdk` and so on, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var findings = Drive.Files.list({ q: query }) || [];
var table = [['name', 'id'], ...findings.items.map(f => [f.title, f.id]).sort()];
```

#### To:

```
var findings = Drive.Files.list({ q: query });
var table = [['name', 'url'], ...findings.items.map(f => [f.title, f.alternateLink]).sort()];
```

Or, in your situation, in order to retrieve the file list in order of title, how about the following modification?

```
var findings = Drive.Files.list({ q: query, maxResults: 1000, orderBy: "title" });
var table = [['name', 'url'], ...findings.items.map(f => [f.title, f.alternateLink])];
```

- `Drive.Files.list` returns 100 items as the default. If your files are more than 100 to 1000, `maxResults: 1000` can be used. If your files are more than 1000, please use `pageToken`.

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve other URL except for `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${id}/view?usp=drivesdk`, `https://docs.google.com/###/d/{id}/edit?usp=drivesdk` and so on, please modify it.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)